# GearVR play video resolution 4K,all the scene would tremble when I turn my head

Tags: unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I develop a app on GearVR to play video, when I play video @resolution 4K all the scene will tremble when I turn my head.I know it`s 30FPS and the multithreadRendering is on.How to resolve this.
P.S. And the multithreadRendering should be on.

Comment: For playing video you use Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie or MovieTexture?

Comment: @V.Borodinov I used EasyMovieTexture plugin,I don`t know clearly which does EasyMovieTexture use.

Comment: May be problem in EasyMovieTexture?

Comment: If I don`t check MultithreadRendering,it work fine, just want find some other way to cross this.